# Contact Process fails when converting Lead

Tags: process-builder, lead-conversion

**What I'm trying to do**

When the Contact Email field is updated, add the Email field value to a custom field in the related Account record.

**How I'm trying to do it**

Using a Process. It is configured like this:

- Choose Object and Specify When to Start the Process

  - Object: Contact
  - Start the process: when a record is created or edited
- Define Criteria for this Action Group

  - Criteria for Executing Actions: Formula evaluates to true
  - Formula:

```
AND(
  NOT(ISNULL([Contact].AccountId )),
OR(
  AND(
    ISNEW(),
    NOT(ISBLANK([Contact].Email))
  ),
 ISCHANGED([Contact].Email)
))
```

- Immediate Actions

  - Record: [Contact].Account ID
  - Criteria for Updating Records:
  - *Field: Primary Contact Email*
  - *Type: Field Reference*
  - *Value: [Contact].Email*

**The problem**

The Process works fine when I update or create Contacts manually. However, when I convert a Lead (which automatically creates a Contact) something weird happens. I get a "An internal server error has occured" message. Here is a link to a screenshot of the error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySXqi.png

I can only successfully convert Leads when I deactivate my Process.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: by definition, an internal server error is a SFDC bug (aka "gack") and should be reported to Support. You should try and reduce the scope of the issue in your sandbox to a trivial PB on Contact, then if that works, add back in successive conditions until it starts to fail